# Android - how to detect touch listener if view has click listener

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener

I have basic layout with linear layout, ScrollView and ImageView.

ScrollView has registered onTouchListener and imageview onClicklistener.
If I tap on ImageView and I am pulling out of ImageView, I do not see log with "onclick".

If I tap out of imageView (on scrollView) and I am pulling somewhere, I see log with "on touch".
How can I catch onTouch event on my imageView, when I am pulling out of it?

**Here is the code:**

```
ImageView testButton = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d(tag, "onclick");

    }
});

ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) myView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(tag, "ontouch");

        return false;
    }
});
```

**And here is xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square"     />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this to your scroll view:

```
ScrollView mainScroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.your_scroll_view)
mainScroll.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
mainScroll.setFocusable(true);  //If you need this
mainScroll.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  //If you need this
```

Then your `imageView` `onclick` listener will be triggered. This code could also substantially affect other parts of your functionality. So please check the view once you implement this and revert if there are any screen jumps which occur.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `OnTouchListener` to the `ImageView` as well. When you pull away the touch from view's touchable region it will fire a Touch event. OnClick wont be fired when the ontouch is cancelled(`MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`).You should not consume the `onTouch()` therefore return false  in `onTouch()`